# why I can't use the 2.5.2 springboot version?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to create a  project usin Spring intializr usen the 2.5.2 spring version, but I'm facing this problem

```
Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.2/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.2.pom
```

[image]

but it works with 2.4.8 version , I'm using iteliJ idea and ubuntu 18.04, also I tried it using spring tool suite, I tried clean it but didn't work.

Comment: Just try again later.

Comment: Look like a network problem: `Transfer failed for https://r...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait until it works again, or you could get and add your own BOM. On maven repository you can 'view files':

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.2/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.2.pom

For some more information on how to add a BOM to your project:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom